# Play iPhone audio in ear speker

Tags: iphone

How can we play audio using the ear speaker from an application. 
The audio plays like some one is talking at the other end of the phone.

Thanks

Comment: Six questions you've asked and haven't accepted answers to any of them? Shame.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like what you're looking for is this:
(from [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007915-CH6-SW46))

**Audio Session Category Route Overrides**

Specifies whether the default audio route for the PlayAndRecord category should be overridden.

```
enum {
   kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None    = 0,
   kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker = 'spkr'
};
```

**Constants**

```
kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None
```

Specifies, for the `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` category, that output audio should go to the receiver. This is the default output audio route for this category.

```
kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker
```

Specifies, for the `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` category, that output audio should go to the speaker, not the receiver.

**Discussion**
The `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` category supports simultaneous input and output. You could use this category, for example, to add an effect to audio coming into the iPhone’s microphone. By default, output audio for this category goes to the receiver—the speaker you hold to your ear when on a phone call. The `kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker` constant lets you direct the output audio to the speaker situated at the bottom of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above, there's also the more permanent solution of `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker` as per this [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1754/_index.html).

Quoth they:

> In contrast, kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker modifies the routing behavior of the kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord category so that audio will always route to the speaker rather than receiver if no other accessory such as headphones are in use.

for reference, Here is the actual code

```
UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;        
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof (doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);
```