# Output sound in iPhone "call" speaker

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I would like to simulate a call in an iPhone app. Is it possible to play a sound in the speaker where you put your ear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found it. looks like I Should use `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord`

[Play iPhone audio in ear speker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191377/play-iphone-audio-in-ear-speker)